# Mustache template with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm trying, without success, to add a javascript to a mustache template

```
<script id="nodeTemplate" type="text/template">
  {{#myItem}}
    <div class="divclass {{#myItemDet}}">
    ...
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     alert('{{#myItemDet}}');
    </script>

  {{/myItem}}
</script>
```

Maybe, it is not possible with Mustache to create JS script...

**--------------------------- NOTE 1**
If a embeed 
`<script type="text/javascript"> ... <script>` 
inside a 
`<script id="nodeTemplate" type="text/template">...</script>`
I suspect that mustache **close the template at the first  tag**

Is it true?

Riccardo

**--------------------------- NOTE 2**
This is my solution:

1) fill with mustache several hidden divs with the class jshidden

2) Search objs with class=jshidden and append div-content as javascript

The solution now work only on Chrome... Still working

http://jsfiddle.net/ric79/zWEUK/

Comment: Regarding NOTE 1: No, it's not mustache it is the browser that closes the template prematurely. mustache will only be able to read the cut-off `script` node as the remainder is being treated as inline text.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the block form for `myItemDet`, rather than the value form.

Try this

```
<script id="nodeTemplate" type="text/template">
  {{#myItem}}
    <div class="divclass {{myItemDet}}">
    ...
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     alert('{{myItemDet}}');
    </script>

  {{/myItem}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to *obfuscate* the ending `</script>` tag to not have the browser's parser take it for an inline script. Split it apart, just like advertisers do when writing to the document (e.g. `document.write('<'+'/script>');`).

Comment: You're right but won't the browser display anything after the first `</script>` tag as inline text?

Comment: no. try it. the whole thing is a long string that is being processed by mustache, its not the DOM processing anything.

Comment: How's the template being included? Via AJAX or is it being served along with the page's markup? The latter would show the issue above.

Comment: it appears to be being added inline, hence the script tags. No, it wouldn't have this "problem". Again, you can try it on trymustache.com - It is a script tag with a custom type attribute. Mustache is able to search for script tags with this attr, and then get .innerText on said tags.

Comment: Sorry but if it is added inline the browser would close the surrounding script tag (i.e. the one with type `text/template`) as soon as it sees the closing tag. trymustache does not show this issue because the template is being taken from a textarea. Go ahead and try to put that template anywhere else in the DOM and you will start to see the issue.

Comment: @Patrick: this issue is not present in trymustache because the template is being taken from a textarea. Try with a vanilla example and you will see the problem.

Comment: @aefxx: this script is inside a array loop. I should use replace not write. But this is "hacking". I would know if mustache supports script inside..

Comment: @Riccardo79 I didn't say you should use `document.write()` (that was just an example where the premature closing is circumvented). What I meant is, try to "escape" the closing script tag somehow, so that it will be correctly assembled by the templating engine before it is handed over to the DOM.

Comment: @aefxx: I mean: putting a placeholder and them replaces all occurrences with "</script>"